# JSTL x:out not working with x:parse

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, taglib

I seem to be unable to use x:out to traverse parsed XML.  I'm looking for ideas on what to check to get this working.  When I take out the x:out the page renders without error so I am assuming x:parse is working fine.  I also use x:transform in this same JSP and it works fine...so it SEEMS like the library setup is correct.

```
<c:catch var="err">
<c:import var="xml" url="http://eip-dev/app/FORMS.xml"/>  
<x:parse doc="${xml}" var="pxml"/>  
<x:out select="$pxml/POL_FORMS/COMPANY"/>  
</c:catch>
<c:out value="${err}"/>
```

This is the XML contained in FORMS.xml:

```
 <POL_FORMS>  
 <COMPANY>ACME CO</COMPANY>  
</POL_FORMS>
```

Getting this error:
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.UnresolvableException: $prefix:javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet

Server info: IBM WebSphere Application Server/6.1
Servlet version: 2.4
JSP version: 2.0
Java version: 1.5.0
JSTL version: 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that JSTL XML taglib is declared as per [JSTL 1.1 tlddoc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html) and that you don't have old JSTL 1.0 libraries (or even the extracted TLD files) wandering around in the classpath.